# Raspberry Pi bootable Android

Tags: pi-3, android, kali

I have a Android device and a 64 GB SD card. I also have an image of Kali Linux on my phone. I don't have a laptop or computer. How do I flash the image to the SD card via my phone.

I would prefer not to root my phone. But I can if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install disk tools on your Android device. The most popular toolkit for this purpose is [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en).

Keep in mind that low-level filesystem access that you need to flash an SD card requires a rooted phone. There are busybox releases which can be installed without rooting, but those won't help you with your task.

Comment: I installed busybox but which toolkit are you suggesting.

Comment: Busybox *is* the toolkit. Determine the device name corresponding to your SD card, and follow the instructions for the image you have downloaded. Usually, the command you need to run is `sudo dd if=image.img of=/dev/sd_card bs=1M` or something similar. One extra thing you may need to install is the shell (sometimes called "terminal"), which may or may not be bundled with busybox.

Comment: I would like to request you to please upload a video of the same as I am still a bit confused.

Comment: @PratikShiveshwar Sorry, but I don't have a rooted android device and I don't plan to root one just to make a video for you. Hope someone else can help.

Comment: Thanx by the way